# Existence proof of subspace of projections from V to W

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Hi I am having some trouble with this proof. I don't know in which direction to start. I was thinking of using the inner product over C and applying the conditions, then showing that the subspace is linear and non empty. Is this a good way to go?

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ and let T:V $\rightarrow$ V be a linear transformation. Suppose that T is idempotent ($T^2$ = T) and self-adjoint (T* = T). Prove that there exists a subspace W of V such that for all v $\in$ V, the vector T(v) is the projection of v onto W.

Edit: Can someone please give a formal proof so I can understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Well, taking $W = {\cal R} T$ would seem like a good start.

Comment: i'm sorry could you please explain more?

Comment: If $x \in W$ then $x = Ty$ for some $y$ and hence $Tx = T^2 y = Ty = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foremost, show that $T^2 = T$ implies that $V = Null(T) \oplus Im(T)$ (when $V$ is finite-dimensional).

(This is relatively easy to do using the containment properties of null spaces and images of powers of T: You need 4 facts to show this:

$$\{0\} \subseteq Null(T) \subseteq Null(T^2) \subseteq  \ ... \ \subseteq Null(T^m) \subseteq \ ... $$

$$ V \supseteq Im(T) \supseteq Im(T^2) \supseteq \ ... \ Im(T^m) \supseteq  \ ...$$

You will also need that (for complex finite dimensional vector spaces): $V = Null(T^n) \oplus Im(T^n)$ (where $dim(V) = n$)

And that if $Null(T) = Null(T^2)$, then $Null(T) = Null(T^m) \ \forall m \geq 2$

If you don't know these facts, there is another way to go about proving that $T^2 = T$ implies $V = Null(T) \oplus Im(T)$ without these, but I personally like this way best.

For the rest of the proof:

We also know that $Null(T) = (Im(T^*))^\perp$.
Since T is self-adjoint, we know that $Im(T^*) = Im(T)$
Hence $Null(T) = (Im(T))^\perp$

As the comment suggested, consider $W = Im(T)$. The previous statement implies $Null(T) = W^\perp$

Then for any $v \in V$, we can write $v = n + w$, where $n \in Null(T) = W^\perp$ and $w \in ImT = W$ (because $V = Null(T) \oplus Im(T)$, as you should verify)

Since $w \in Im(T)$, write $ w = T(u)$ for some $u \in V$.

Then $T(v) = T(n + w) = T(n + T(u)) = T^2(u) = T(u) = w$.

This is exactly the definition of an orthogonal projection map onto W.